# Multiple constraints on single column

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Can we add multiple constraints on a single column?

like-

```
create table x(x varchar2(20), y number(2) not null,
constraint fk_cons foreign key(x) references user_info(user_id),
constraint null_cons not null(x)
)
```

this query is returning error ora-00904: invalid identifier....

Comment: i am assuming the user_info table exists and user_id column exists in that table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have wrong syntax when create `null_cons` constraint:

Use this (table level check constraint):

```
CREATE TABLE x(
    x VARCHAR2(20), 
    y NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_cons FOREIGN KEY(x) REFERENCES user_info(user_id),
    CONSTRAINT null_cons CHECK(x IS NOT NULL)
)
```

Or (use `NOT NULL` constraint on column):

```
CREATE TABLE x(
    x VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
    y NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_cons FOREIGN KEY(x) REFERENCES user_info(user_id)
)
```

Or (Use column level check constraint):

```
CREATE TABLE x(
    x VARCHAR2(20) CHECK (X IS NOT NULL), 
    y NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT fk_cons FOREIGN KEY(x) REFERENCES user_info(user_id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    create table x(x varchar2(20), y number(2) not null,
    constraint fk_cons foreign key(x) references user_info(user_id),
    constraint null_cons check(x is not null)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If the RDBMS is SQL Server, you can define multiple constraints at the column by doing this (I changed some of the column names to make the constraint naming strategy more obvious - naming is subjective):

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable(
    User_Id VARCHAR(20) CONSTRAINT FK_SomeTable_User_Id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.User_Info(User_Id) CONSTRAINT UIX_NC_SomeTable_User_id  NONCLUSTERED NOT NULL, 
    SomeOtherColumn DECIMAL(2, 0) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table x(x varchar2(20) not null, y number(2) not null,
    constraint fk_cons foreign key(x) references user_info(user_id)
)
```